# Liquibase with Springboot and application-<level>.yml creating sql for e.g. level = prod

Tags: spring-boot, maven, liquibase

we have couple of application yaml files, depending on the level (dev, staging, prod).
Now on staging & prod we are not allowed to change schema.
I tried to figure out how to issue the "updateSQL" command from https://docs.liquibase.com/workflows/liquibase-community/generate-sql-update-schemas.html?Highlight=output%20sql%20to%20file

In the pom.xml we only have the dependency to liquibase-core.
Every other configuration is in the different yaml files (url, driver, user, pw etc.).

So I'd like to have that the SQL scriot genereated with labels etc. on startup of the application or with mvn liquibase:updateSQL (but without configuring it on the pom.xml).

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. One can use
https://docs.liquibase.com/workflows/liquibase-community/offline.html
in the liquibase.properties then it doesn't need a specific URL and will create independently SQL.